# defining Priority for agents in service block in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I have developed a discrete-event model in the field of freight transportation in AnyLogic. I have an agent named "truck" and I defined a parameter named "refrigerator" in its page and with the command <randomTrue(0.15)> in the default value box, I devote 15 percent of the truck population to refrigerator trucks ". In the flowchart, trucks would go to parking by using MoveTo block and then will receive a service by Service block.
I want to define a situation that those 15 percent trucks (refrigerator) that separated with parameter have periority in receiving service in compare to other 85 percent trucks so that spend much less time in parking.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF. Please clarify your question: trucks are resources or agents using resources? Best share some screenshots or add some more details. "define a situation which the labled trucks separated with defined parameter conduct their service process with periority to others." does not really make sense :)

Comment: I tried to revise my question precisely. Hope you could help me :) @Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set the Service queue size to 1 (so we do not really use it)
2. Drag a Queue object before the service
3. Change the queuing type to "Agent comparison" and prefer agents with `refrigerator == true` as below (read the help on Queue to understand this and other options)

[image]